# How do I auto-sum two boxes into a different box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two boxes, one named `AuthorizedAmount` and another named `LessLaborToDate`:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Authorized Amount</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="AuthorizedAmount" min=0 step="0.01" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Less Labor to Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="LessLaborToDate" min=0 step="0.01" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I get these two values automatically summed in another box, *named* Subtotal?

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Subtotal</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Subtotal" placeholder="Authorized Amount minus Less Labor to Date" min=0 step="0.01" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apply an `input` event handler to both boxes, then retrieve their values and add them. If you have a specific issue with that, please post the JS code you've tried.

Comment: @freedomn-m I've not - I couldn't think of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery, something like this:

```
$("input[name='AuthorizedAmount'], input[name='LessLaborToDate']").change(function() {
    var sum = $("input[name='AuthorizedAmount']").val() + $("input[name='LessLaborToDate']").val();
    $("input[name='Subtotal']").val(sum);
});
```

You might need to add some null checks and `parseInt` but you get the idea I hope

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try.

Comment: When I try, it will capture either the number from AuthorizedAmount or the number from LessLaborToDate in the Subtotal box, but not both. For some reason it clears the Subtotal box when I try adding a number to both AuthorizedAmount  and LessLaborToDate

Comment: You might need to do `parseInt` before adding the two values `var sum = parseInt($("input[name='AuthorizedAmount']").val()) + parseInt($("input[name='LessLaborToDate']").val());`

Comment: Perfect - when I prepend with parseInt it captures the whole amount. Is there a way for it to capture decimal amounts? For example, if I am adding 100.23 and 100.48, it will only display the whole number amount of **200**

Comment: Try using `parseFloat` instead